# Regular expressions, xslt 2, basics

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, regex-group

I have went through several examples and tried to modify my search to understand what is what.

Input:

```
<Description>Ottelu pelattu 22.4.2018. Gagarin Cupin 5. finaaliottelu. Selostus: Antti Mäkinen.</Description>
<Description>Ottelu pelattu 20.4.2018. Gagarin Cupin 1. finaaliottelu. Selostus: Antti Mäkinen.</Description>
<Description>Ottelu pelattu 22.4.2018. Gagarin Cupin 2. puolivälierä. Selostus: Antti Mäkinen.</Description>`
```

What I want to do is select these to my output:

- "Gagarin Cupin 5. finaaliottelu"
- "Gagarin Cupin 2. puolivälierä"

Without the dot there in the middle.

I could use substring-before/after, but I understand it could be useful to use regex?

I have made this that fetches what I need: `Gagarin Cupin\s\d\W\s\w*[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]*`

But now how can I use this in XSLT? Is it `analyze-string()` that I should use? or `matches()` in some way?

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="episode" select="Description"/>
<xsl:variable name="fetchcup">
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$episode" regex="Gagarin Cupin\s\d\W\s\w*[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]*">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
           </xsl:variable>
<Cup><xsl:value-of select="$fetchcup"/></Cup>
```

But honestly, I feel like I am missing some basics of how it works despite looking through tutorial pages and examples. If I get a foot in the door I can apply it further.

Comment: Consider to show us some minimal but complete samples of the input and the XSLT to demonstrate the problem, with the output you want and the one you get. It is currently not clear whether you have these `Description` elements as sibling elements of a common parent element and whether you then have the `<xsl:variable name="episode" select="Description"/>` in a template matching the parent and there select all of the `Description` elements and expect to use the `analyze-string` on all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression works in the context of a single `Description` element, inside of the `xsl:matching-substring` if you want to output the matched string you can simply use `.` for the context item or `regex-group(0)` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-regex-group). The use of `regex-group(1)` doesn't make sense in your case as your regular expression does not have any subexpressions.

```
  <xsl:template match="Description">
      <cup>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Gagarin Cupin\s\d\W\s\w*[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß]*">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>          
      </cup>
  </xsl:template>
```

That template in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQH outputs

```
<cup>Gagarin Cupin 5. finaaliottelu</cup>
<cup>Gagarin Cupin 1. finaaliottelu</cup>
<cup>Gagarin Cupin 2. puolivälierä</cup>
```

for your three `Description` elements, I hope I understood that correctly as the desired output.

Comment: Note that the pattern can be simplified since I think, under your control, that the `\w` character class already contains unicode letters: `Gagarin Cupin\s+\d+\.\s+\w+` or `Gagarin Cupin \d+\. \w+`. Whatever, thanks to make me discover that a xslt fiddle exists.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks for pointing that out, thanks to you or whoever created https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQH/1 to demonstrate it works.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This solved my problem. And I learned how to designate regex-groups.